# Non-promise problems that are BQP complete, and showing them to be or not to be in NP

Tags: complexity-theory, bqp

Whenever we discuss "BQP" as a complexity class, we often are really talking about "Promise-BQP" instead of BQP.

And the same goes for BQP-complete problems, all that I can find are either not decision problems, or promise problems.

Are there any known BQP-complete problems that are strictly decision problems (without a promise for the input to satisfy)? And if there are, wouldn't it be easy to determine whether this problem was in NP, and therefore if BQP is contained in NP or not? For example, it's fairly easy to prove that a problem has no possible "certificate" for every input that's polynomially sized, right?

Comment: BQP without a promise has no (known) complete problems. Same as BPP, and AM, and QMA, etc.  The title of your post is not clear to me?

Comment: Also, it’s not entirely trivial as to whether a problem has a polynomial sized certificate. This can be seen with, e.g., polynomial identity testing, which is known to be in BPP, but not in NP. But many people believe it’s probably even in P!

Comment: @MarkS Thanks for the response; your comment answers my question. The title was just asking *if* a non-promise problem is known to be BQP-complete, and if it did exist, why it isn't easy to show it is in NP. Yeah, it isn't always trivial to determine if a problem is in NP, I guess that part of my question isn't completely true.